# Latest post by different users

Tags: django

Post has user and date attributes.

How can I turn this

```
posts = Post.objects.order_by('-date')[:30]
```

to give me 30 or less posts consisting of the last post by every user?

For example if I have 4 posts stored, 3 are from post.user="Benny" and 1 from post.user="Catherine" it should return 1 post from Benny and 1 from Catherine ordered by date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would probably use [`annotate`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/models/querysets/#annotate), you might be able to use [`extra`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/models/querysets/#extra) to get down to a single query.

```
posts = []
for u in User.objects.annotate(last_post=Max('post__date')).order_by('-last_post')[:30]:
    posts.append(u.post_set.latest('date'))
```

You could also use [`raw`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/db/sql/), which would let you write a SQL query, but still return model instances. For instance:

```
sql = """
SELECT * FROM app_post
WHERE app_post.date IN
    (SELECT MAX(app_post.date) FROM app_post
     GROUP BY app_post.user_id)
ORDER BY app_post.date DESC
"""
posts = list(Post.objects.raw(sql))
```

Comment: I agree with you. But, there should be `order_by('-last_post')` and `posts.append(u.post_set.latest('date'))` to get **latest** posts.

Comment: @srusskih Yeah that helps, eh?

Answer (score 0):

untested but you might be able to do this

```
from django.db.models import Max
Post.objects.all().annotate(user=Max('date'))
```